# php class extends

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I want to know is it possible to have a class that's extended have a var set and used from the base class?

eg:

```
class me
{
    public $hello = array();

    protected function setter($me)
    {
        $this->hello[] = $me;
    }
}

class foo extends me
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setter('foo');
    }
}

class yoo extends me
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::setter('yoo');
    }
}

$me = new me();
$foo = new foo();
$yoo = new yoo();

print_r($me->hello);
```

the array printed is array() nothing is set.

Comment: It seems that what you are trying to do here is not set a var on the base class but set a var on an instance of the base class. The ***class*** `me` may be the base for the classes `foo` and `yoo` but the ***object*** `$me` is not the base of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by making `$hello` [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

```
public static $hello = array();
```

In doing so, you will have to drop the `$this` from `$this->hello[] = $me;` and replace it with a `self`, as `hello` will not longer be unique to the current object instance:

```
self::$hello[] = $me;
```

Comment: Cool and all I do is make a getter that does return self::$hello;

Comment: This is correct, but keep in mind that there will now be only one $hello for all instances of `me` and all of its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You were using

```
parent::setter('yoo');
```

But in parent class me, that function is not defined as static. So you cannot use :: to call un-static function.